# Unable to send email through apche server on ubuntu using codeigniter.. but i can send email from local

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

> Failed to authenticate password. Error: 
> Unable to send email
> using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using
> this method.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']   = 'smtp.office365.com';
$config['smtp_port']   = 587;
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls'; // Use 'ssl' if TLS is not working
$config['smtp_user']   = 'xxxxxxxx'; // username(email address)
$config['smtp_pass']   = 'xxxxxxx'; //App password
$config['charset']     = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype']    = 'text';
$config['newline']     = "\r\n";
$this->email->from('xxxxxxxx', 'test');
$this->email->to('xxxxxxxx@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Testing');
$this->email->message('Your message here.');
if ($this->email->send()) {
echo 'Email sent successfully.';
    } else {
        echo 'Email sending failed.';
        echo $this->email->print_debugger(); // Print any debugging information
    }
```

Comment: *Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method* Did you contact your server support?

Answer (score 0):

The `print_debugger()` output should include details of the SMTP headers/messages used. You may have more information that would be useful.

> Failed to authenticate password

You have connected to the SMTP server, and you have sent it the username and password, and it has not accepted these. This could be because one of them is not valid. Or the email provider may be doing some other other authentication checks, such as IP location, or multi-factor authentication. If the exact same code works when you run it locally, then it is possible that your current IP address is "trusted".